# Mariadb running out of memory

Tags: centos, mysql, mariadb

I have an old web server that's been running for some time, with regular updates. For the last month it's been crashing every few days. I tracked it down to:

```
$ dmesg
Out of memory in UB 136: OOM killed process 28109 (mysqld) score 0 vm:413300kB, rss:17588kB, swap:9168kB
```

(curiously, it's the only line in dmesg).

I just use mysql for simple stuff in PHP, there's no reason it should need more than a few K of memory. And it's been running like that for a long time. I haven't changed the PHP code recently, but I updated the server (apache, mysql, php, etc) last month, it's on Centos 7.

My guess is that something I was doing before didn't matter and now it does, like forgetting to close or release something.

What can I do to track this issue further ?

Comment: First thing, check the Apache, MariaDB, etc... logs.

Comment: If you gathering stats of sql queries check, the volume and slow queries. For sure mysql was the highest memory consumer, so system killed mysql. Also check what other process need more memory. And what how much memory available system wide.

Comment: Upon restart mysql is using 11% of system memory. Don't see anything in apache logs. Don't know how to check sql logs: systemctl mariadb doesn't have much.

Comment: https://docs.hypernode.com/troubleshooting/performance/how-to-debug-out-of-memory-oom-events.html